# NPN Transistor To Control LED Strip

Tags: arduino, transistors, led, npn

I am new to the use of transistors and couldn't find exactly how to select the right transistor for this type of an application which is to control a 5m 5050 RGB LED strip with an Arduino. The LED strip has 4 pins (R/G/B/12V) so I would need 3 transistors for R,G and B. The LED strip has 300 LEDs (60LEDs/m) and each LED consumes 20mA max current so the max current through any transistor would be 6A. I believe the Arduino outputs at 5V so the input to the base of the transistor would be 5V.

I came across the NPN 2N2222 transistor however its [datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/PN2222-D.PDF) shows the following which states that its max collector current is 600mA so I am led to believe that I would need a transistor with a higher collector current.

[image: datasheet of the NPN 2N2222]

I also found the TIP102 NPN transistor ([datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/TIP100-D.PDF)) which is has a higher max collector current of 8A which is sufficient for its use. It also has a base voltage of 5V and a max collector-emitter voltage of 100V which is also sufficent.

[image: datasheet of the NPN TIP102 transistor]

I also came across the IRLZ34N MOSFET ([datasheet](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irlz34n.pdf)) however am not familiar with MOSFETs.

Would the TIP102 transistor work for my use of controlling an LED strip with the 5V arduino?

Comment: Don't confuse Absolute Maximum ratings with operational ratings.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams so should it be fine seeing that the maximum ratings are much above my use for it?

Comment: Go for a mosfet.

Comment: @Andyaka could you advice which one as I'm clueless in selecting them. Would the IRLZ34N work?

Comment: Bipolar transistors amplify current.  You should design around 10mA max output current for an Arduino pin and you need 6 amps, so you need a transistor beta of 600 (beta is the current gain of the transistor).  To get a beta this high you would almost certainly have to use a darlington transistor which is two transistors in series.

A better idea would be to use a logic level mosfet, take a look at the irl540 or similar.

Comment: The IRLZ34N will work for your application.

Comment: @DeanFranks The datasheet for the IRL540 says that the continuous drain current when Vgs=5V (Tc=25C) would be 28A, how would I reduce this to the 6A which I need? Thank you for your help

Comment: You don't have to.  The power supply must be able to source at least as much current as required by the load.  The load will only draw what it needs so as long as 28A > 6A (and you have sufficient heat-sinking) you are fine.

Comment: @DeanFranks Please stop answering questions in the comment field. As you can see, it has now attracted a reply, which you will have to iterate on with OP. The comment section is not meant for that.

Comment: @DeanFranks what makes you think the IRL540 is better than the OP’s choice of IRLZ34N?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose a logic level type Nfet for a low side switch Source= 0V such that RdsOn*I^2=Pd is cool  <0.25W without a heatsink .

It will probably be rated 10x the load current you plan to use.  There are far more SMD choices.

Otherwise

Comment: Thank you very much. Just to confirm the IRLZ34N should be fine?

Comment: if you analyze it thermally. RdsOn rises 50% at 100'C but 0.046Ω at Vgs=5V only at 25'C  thus 6A * 0.046 *150% * 62'C/W= 25'C rise at 40'C internal ambient = 65'C passes the sniff test. But heatspread it if in a sealed box. Idmax=30A@25'C so 6x load, is OK if above is true. Tj=85'C max under any condition is OK.